# Adding an extra class to the last element of the navigation/tree menu

Tags: 8, theming, navigation

For one of my projects, I have to create a tree menu, with parents and children, that would be used to navigate through the website. The parents are collapsible. Below is the twig file that I am using to generate the menu:

```
{% macro menu_links(menu_tree, route_tid, current_depth, max_depth, collapsible) %}
{% import _self as macros %}
{% for item in menu_tree %}
  {%
    set liClass = [
      item.subitem and current_depth < max_depth ? 'menu-item menu-item--expanded block-taxonomymenu__menu-item block-taxonomymenu__menu-item--expanded' : 'menu-item block-taxonomymenu__menu-item',
      route_tid == item.tid ? 'menu-item--active block-taxonomymenu__menu-item--active' : ''
    ]
  %}

  <li class="{{ liClass|join(' ') }}">
    {% if item.image %}
      <img class="menu-item-image block-taxonomymenu__image" src="{{ item.image }}" {% if item.use_image_style == false %}height="{{ item.height }}" width="{{ item.width }}"{% endif %} />
    {% endif %}
    <span class="levels">
      <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="block-taxonomymenu__link {% if route_tid == item.tid %}active block-taxonomymenu__link--active{% endif %}">{{ item.name }}{% if item.show_count == true %} [{{ item.nodes|length }}]{% endif %}</a>
    </span>
    {% if item.subitem and current_depth < max_depth %}
      {% if item.interactive_parent %}
        <i class="far fa-plus-square parent-toggle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      {% endif %}
      {% if collapsible == TRUE %}
        <ul class="menu block-taxonomymenu__submenu collapsed-submenu">
      {% else %}
        <ul class="menu block-taxonomymenu__submenu">
      {% endif %}
        {{ macros.menu_links(item.subitem, route_tid, current_depth + 1, max_depth, collapsible) }}
      </ul>
    {% endif %} 
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

{% endmacro %}

I wanted to know if it was possible to add an extra class to the last li class of the tree menu? I have actually tried to add **current_depth == max_depth ? 'item--last': ''** in the setliClass and **{% if 
     current_depth == max_depth %}item--last{% endif %}"** in the li class="{{ liClass|join(' ') }}" part, but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply an additional loop to iterate by specific menu_level. Here is an example of a twig template that iterates over menu level variable:
[How to add classes to menu items in navigation twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/229142/79832)

Then use a condition to set the class within the for loop such as:

loop.last ? 'last'

See all the variables associated with for loops in twig here: 
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html